# Online PHP documentation tool

Tags: php, documentation-generator

I'm searching for a documentation generation software like [phpDocumentor](http://phpdoc.org) or [phpDox](http://phpdox.de) for scripts written in PHP.

As both mentioned softwares are running with root permissions (apparently), I can't use them because I'm on a shared server, so the installation on a shared server is the most important point in my search.

I'm allowed to run some shell scripts but not all commands. So I can e.g. use nothing that requires root permissions, which also includes "installing packages". This makes a web-based solution preferable.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: As I'm informed, that should be possible with the built-in [reflection API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) without the need of some additional tools: "PHP 5 comes with a complete reflection API that adds the ability to reverse-engineer classes, interfaces, functions, methods and extensions. Additionally, the reflection API offers ways to retrieve doc comments for functions, classes and methods." ([source](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.reflection.php))

Comment: Good idea, but with this (I already used this to get some child classes) I'd need to script the documentation by myself. With all styles and so on. But I will give it a try, although I'd appreciate more recommendations for softwares.

Comment: Some references for that: [How to create documentation using Reflection](http://runnable.com/UnI4L-A6XHZ6AAAa/how-to-create-documentation-using-reflection-for-php) / [What is Reflection in PHP?](http://culttt.com/2014/07/02/reflection-php/) – and [phpDocumentor/Reflection](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/Reflection) could be the "documentation generation software" you're looking for (not tried myself, hence a comment and not an answer).

Comment: Looks quite interesting, may be this works. Thank you!

Comment: My thoughts (as I may be in need of something like that as well to get up-to-date – still using the very same tool I've used for about 15 years now, and that hasn't been updated for a while ;)

Comment: What a pity - which tool are you using?

Comment: A pretty ancient version of PhpDocGen (the tool seems to be discontinued, its URL throws a 404). Ah, no: just moved [here](http://www.arakhne.org/phpdocgen/). Looks like I've missed a bunch of updates #D

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend [http://phpfui.com](http://phpfui.com/?n=PHPFUI%5CInstaDoc) for this. Runs as a PHP script right on your server.  Will produce static files if you need them for high volume sites. Easy to install and set up. Maybe 2 minutes to usable documentation for your code and all the third party code you use in your app.